# Keyboard wrong with some application

Tags: debian, keyboard

I-m using Debian 10.
I write from Italy, my keyboard setup is set on italian.
If I write on text editor, all works correctly.
But here in mozilla, or in other software like libreCAD, the keyboard is not correct. For example, if I want to write colon, I obtain the inequality sign `>`.
I I want to write quotation mark, I obtain `@`.
And so on.
All starts today, I don't remember exactly when, if I installed a new software or something similar.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The character differences look like you might be getting the US English keyboard layout instead of the Italian one.

Your desktop environment may include a feature that allows you to switch keyboard layouts at will. Often such a feature will try and remember which layout was in use in each application, and will try to adjust the layout settings when you move between applications. And sometimes it will get the default state wrong, or perhaps you have once accidentally pressed the layout switching key combination in that application, and then the desktop environment remembers it forever...

If you don't need to switch between US English and Italian keyboard layouts, go to the keyboard settings of your desktop environment and ensure that the list of keyboard layouts available for quick switching has only the Italian layout in it.

If you do need the layout switching feature, I'd recommend that you also enable the layout indicator feature that usually comes with it. Then you can easily verify which layout is selected in each application, and switch it as necessary.

Comment: I'm try to do:
    $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

And I choose italian keyboard. Then, I reboot, but nothing changed.

Comment: The `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` just selects the system-wide *default* keyboard. The desktop environment can, and often will, provide per-user settings and extra functionality like quick switching between the layouts. These will override the system-wide default.

Comment: Ok Thanks, but how can I modify these changes? Maybe (but I'm not sure) the problem happen after the installation of AnyDesk

Answer (score 0):

just installed debian 10 and found the same problem

there is something wrong with the italian keyboard layout... i mean: if you open region and language and go under input sources, when you display the italian keyboard the system displays (at least in my case) an us keyboard.

i managed to solve the problem by adding geoargian (italy) layout.

it behaves like a bug, since by simply adding that layout, also the italian layout started working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue after installing AnyDesk (as you said in one of your comment) on Debian 10 with Gnome.

I am forced to use `setxkbmap fr` every time I reboot in order to have my keyboard layout in chromium.

Based on [another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451945/permanently-set-keyboard-layout-options-with-setxkbmap-in-gnome-unity), it's possible to configure xkb in Xorg config in order to have it on boot, but I am wondering if you found a solution?